# \renewcommand{\refname}{} does not remove "References"

Tags: bibliographies, article

I have a file of class "article" with bibliography style "nature"
Since I want to have the references in the table of contents with a section number, i have set a section with the references inside and now want to hide the automatically set title "References"

As far as I know, `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` should do the magic, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Please, a minimal example with the necessary packages is needed. For example, the `natbib` package changes the definition of the bibliography section.

Comment: thanks, egreg. packages was indeed the problem because of the order of commands.

Comment: @stefan -- *which* packages are you loading?

Comment: I resolved that same issue with `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` right after `\bibliographystyle`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are loading the package `natbib`, then

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}
```

after `\usepackage[<options>]{natbib}` will get rid of the section automatically provided (and also of the blank space you'd get by only redefining `\refname` or `\bibname`).

Comment: this didn't work for me. I am using `\usepackage{apalike}`. I could suppress "References" if I used `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` right before the `\bibliography{cite}` command. But still had the extra space.

Comment: @jerlich Please, ask a fresh question with all the details.

Comment: my question was answered by a combination of the answers in this post. so a fresh question seems duplicative.

Answer (score 3):

For my part I used these command:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} % bib style
    %%% change name of biliography
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{} %%no name
```

I just tested it on a article I wrote and it worked fine.

[image]

Comment: Note that this will usually produce the same vertical white space that `\section*{}` would produce. This additional spacing may not always be wanted.

Comment: In my case I want to rename the bibliography, but `\refname` is undefined. Using `\bibname` does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `babel`, the following might work.

- for book or report class: `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{}}`
- for article class: `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\refname}{}}`

The provided solution only works when the babel package with the english option is used. Without this package the redefinition is as simple as shown in other answer.