# Title of the bibliography using BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, titles, bibunits

I am rather new in BibTeX. I want to print the bibliography without a title, and I am using the command

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{}
```

for this. Printing of the bibliography is coded as:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

This works, but it leaves a big empty vertical space (where the word References was printed with a huge font). How I can remove it? Please note that I am going to use the package '''bibunits''' also. Many thanks in advance!

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[a5paper, left = 10 mm, top = 5 mm, right = 10 mm, bottom = 15 mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\refname}{}

\begin{document}
Somebody said nothing~\cite{Dub1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code of the .bib file:

```
@article {Dub1,
AUTHOR = {Somebody},
TITLE = {Something},
JOURNAL = {Uspekhi Mat. Nauk},
FJOURNAL = {Rossi\u{\i}skaya Akademiya Nauk. Moskovskoe Matematicheskoe
Obshchestvo. Uspekhi Matematicheskikh Nauk},
VOLUME = {0},
YEAR = {1909},
NUMBER = {1)},
PAGES = {1--2},
ISSN = {2-3},
MRCLASS = {30C57},
MRNUMBER = {334360},
MRREVIEWER = {Adam},
DOI = {10.5093/rm0171},
URL = {https://doi.org/70.9023/rm2071},
}
```

Comment: Usually bibliographies get a `\section*` (for `article`-like classes) or a `\chapter*` (for `report`- and `book`-like classes) heading. With `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` you make sure that you issue an empty heading (`\section*{}` or `\chapter*{}`), this can mean that the spacing the heading would create is still there. The exact heading structure depends on your document class as well as the bibliography packages you are loading. We need to see a small example document (and not just a few code snippets) that show what you are seeing: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22645/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48312/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132646/35864 (this one is specific to a particular document class setup, but the general principle can be applied elsewhere).

Comment: Dear colleagues, how I can answer you? I cannot print enough code in the comment environment. Should I edit question itself?

Comment: Absolutely. You can always edit your question to include the necessary info. (In fact you shouldn't include code examples that are needed to understand the question in the comments. The idea being that the question should be self-contained and that comments should only be used to ask for clarification.)

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question. Should I post the code of the .bib file?

Comment: Just of the example entry `Dub1`. If the entry is not important you could use an entry of the pre-installed `xampl.bib` instead (if you were using `biblatex`, `biblatex-examples.bib` would be the go-to example file).

Comment: Please find the code of the .bib file.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. For this situation the nicest answer (IMHO) is the one from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132646/35864: Use `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}` instead of `\renewcommand{\refname}{}`. This completely removes the code to typeset the section title from the bibliography, so that you don't even print an empty heading.

Comment: Many thanks! Just I have compiled, I have found another question) It is also small vertical distance between the end of the bibliography and further text. How can I remove this also?

Comment: At least in the MWE that appears to be the normal distance inserted by a list environment. I would probably leave it as it is, because otherwise things get really ... cosy.

Comment: Many thanks, moewe!